# Java: Insert a JFreeChart graphic into a powerPoint (pptx) as a vectorGraphic

Tags: java, export, jfreechart, vector-graphics

I am generating graphs which I have to export into a powerPoint. I figured out how to convert the graph into a png and insert it into the powerPoint. However this is not ideal, if you want to zoom into the graph. Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XMLSlideShow;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.apache.batik.svggen.*;
import org.apache.poi.sl.usermodel.PictureData.PictureType;
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFPictureData;
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFPictureShape;
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFSlide;
import org.apache.batik.svggen.SVGGraphics2D;

/**
 *
 * @author vsolotyc
 */
public class JFreeChartToPpt {
    public void createPpt() throws Exception{
        // Create a new PPTX file
        XMLSlideShow ppt = new XMLSlideShow();
        
         // Create a new slide
        XSLFSlide slide = ppt.createSlide();
        
        // Generate a graph using JFreeChart
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createLineChart(
                "Graph Title", // chart title
                "X Axis", // x axis label
                "Y Axis", // y axis label
                null, // dataset
                PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, // orientation
                true, // include legend
                true, // tooltips
                false // urls
                );
        
        // Convert the graph to a BufferedImage
        BufferedImage image = chart.createBufferedImage(500, 300);
          
        // Add the image to the slide
        byte[] imageData = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", baos);
        imageData = baos.toByteArray();
        XSLFPictureData pd = ppt.addPicture(imageData, PictureType.PNG);
        XSLFPictureShape pic = slide.createPicture(pd);
        pic.setAnchor(new Rectangle(50, 50, 500, 300));
        
        // Save the PPTX file
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("example.pptx");
        ppt.write(out);
        out.close();
    }
}
```

When exporting the graphs to pdf, the graphics are converted into vector graphics.

Question: What is the best way to export the graphs into a powerPoint as vector graphics (similar to the pdf).

(Here is the link that shows how the pdf export works: https://thinktibits.blogspot.com/2011/05/pdf-add-chart-itext-example-jfreechart.html)

Comment: I can't find anything that exports jfreechart as a vector grapohics object - not in you code or in the example you refer to. It's all bitmaps.

Comment: Maybe you can use [another link](https://thinktibits.blogspot.com/2013/01/JFreechart-Create-SVG-Pie-Bar-Chart-Java-Example-Program.html) in the same domain, which shows how to use Apache Batik (for SVGs) with JFreeChart.

Comment: My previous comment can be misunderstood as ironic, but it is not. It is just a suggestion.

Comment: @JustanotherJavaprogrammer the example in the link is not bitmap, it is vector graphic. At least when you zoom in the pdf it looks perfectly sharp.

Comment: @gthanop I was thinking about this approach, though it seems expensive to convert the graph into SVG and then add it to the slide. The pptx might blow up in size as well since I have around 100 slides. However I will try this approach if everything else false.

Comment: Excuse me, it seems like the link I provided is exporting the PPT to SVG, not embedding a SVG to the PPT. My bad.

Comment: @KJ If I create a SVG and add it to Powerpoint, it actually looks pretty descent. So I will try this route. JFreeChart -> SVG -> Add to pptx.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up converting the jFreeChart graphic into a svg, which I then added to a pptx. It is pretty fast and keeps the pptx fairly small.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XMLSlideShow;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFPictureData;
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFPictureShape;
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFSlide;
import org.jfree.graphics2d.svg.SVGGraphics2D;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.apache.poi.sl.usermodel.PictureData;
import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset;

public class JFreeChartToPpt {

    int WIDTH = 600;
    int HEIGHT = 450;

     public void createPptFromFreeChartViaSvg() throws Exception{
        // Create a new PPTX file
        XMLSlideShow ppt = new XMLSlideShow();
        
         // Create a new slide
        XSLFSlide slide = ppt.createSlide();
        
        // Generate a graph using JFreeChart
        JFreeChart chart = generateChart();
        
        // Convert the graph to a vector graphic
        SVGGraphics2D g2 = new SVGGraphics2D(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
         Rectangle r = new Rectangle(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
         chart.draw(g2, r);
         String svgXml = g2.getSVGDocument().toString();
        
        byte[] svgBytes = svgXml.getBytes();
        
        // adjust size and position
        Dimension slideSize = ppt.getPageSize();
        Rectangle2D anchor = new Rectangle2D.Double(
            slideSize.getWidth()/2 - WIDTH/2,  // Center horizontally
            slideSize.getHeight()/2 - HEIGHT/2, // Center vertically
            WIDTH,                            // Width
            HEIGHT                             // Height
        );
        
        // Add the SVG image to a PowerPoint presentation
        XSLFPictureData pictureData = ppt.addPicture(svgBytes, PictureData.PictureType.SVG);
        XSLFPictureShape pictureShape = slide.createPicture(pictureData);
        pictureShape.setAnchor(anchor);

        // Save the updated PowerPoint presentation
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("exampleSvg_"+WIDTH+"x"+HEIGHT+".pptx");
        ppt.write(out);
        out.close();
    }
}
```